# Call specific variable in function

Tags: python, variables

Somebody can help me how to access specific variable from other function in Python?

```
class A:
    me = None
    def __init__(self):
        self.me = self.me

    def something(self, other):
        other = other
        self.me = "its me to change"
        return other #this function just return 'other' only.

    def call_me(self):
        something = A().something
        print something.__get__(self.me) #get variable 'self.me' only from function of 'something'

A().call_me()
```

We need only show `self.me` in my function of `call_me(self):`
So, if we call `A().call_me()`, the output is `its me to change`.

**Edit:**

```
class A:
    def something(self, other):
        other = other
        me = "its me to change"
        return other

    def call_me(self):
        something = A().something
        #get variable 'me' only from function of something

A().call_me()
```

Comment: No this is bad coding and you should stop doing it. Anything outside the function should never creep inside the function trying to fine a variable inside that function. If you want the `self.me` variable just use `self.me` variable. If you want to know what `something` is setting that variable to then that is not right because it introduces tight coupling between `something` and `call_me` and `call_me` should not have a knowledge/depend on `something` in terms of that class variable. You rather call `self.something(other)` and then access `self.me` afterwards. A function should be a black box.

Comment: Your code is strange. [What are you _really_ trying to achieve](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: humbb ok2.. but, possible me to access it variable from another function without varibale `self.me` in above of class? or how best alternative should I do?

Comment: Maybe I did not understood what you want to achieve, but can't you just write a "get" method that returns the "self.me" variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you did not fully understand how Python objects work.

```
class A:
    me = None
```

Here, you declare a attribute of class A, what would be called a static attribute in other OO languages => it is shared between all objects of the class

```
class A:
    ...
    def __init__(self):
        self.me = self.me
```

Almost a no-op: you override the static attribute A.me with an object attribute with same name and same value. The only effect if that when you create an object of class A it has a private copy:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> id(a.me) = id(A.me) # same value ?
True
>>> id(a.me) is id(A.me) # same object
False
```

Let's continue

```
class A:
    ...
    def something(self, other):
        other = other
        self.me = "its me to change"
        return other #this function just return 'other' only.
```

- `other = other` is really a no-op
- `self.me = ...` sets the value of the *object* attribute `me` - you can now access this new value in any other method as `self.me` or from the outside as `a.me` (if `a` is an object of class `A`) - if would be the same even if you had not done `self.me = self.me` in `__init__`

Last but not least:

```
class A:
    ...
    def call_me(self):
        something = A().something
        print something.__get__(self.me) # ???
```

- `something = A().something`: declares a new object of class `A` and make the local variable `something` point to the `something` method of that object - as the variable is local to the method, **that new object will be destroyed on method exit**
- `print something.__get__(self.me)`: does nothing, as you never call the `something` method, so just display, so you get:

  ```
  >>> a = A()  # create an object a of class A
  >>> a.call_me()   # call call_me method on that object
  <bound method A.something of <__main__.A instance at ...>>
  >>> A().call_me()   # directly call `call_me` on a temporary object
  ...
  TypeError: __get__(None, None) is invalid
  ```

because in first case you just print the *local variable* something as `self` is a valid object (`a`), while in second case it is just a temporary

---

I assume that want you wanted is simply:

```
class A:
    def something(self, other):
        self.me = "its me to change"  # sets the attribute 'me'
        return other #this function just return 'other' only.

    def call_me(self):
        self.something(None)  # call something on self => sets  self.me
        print self.me #get variable 'self.me' after setting it in 'something'
```

You get now as expected:

```
>>> A().call_me()
its me to change
```

Comment: Very good answer! You understood what the OP was *really* trying to do, and showed him how to do it *right* (and cleared up his misunderstandings in the process).